# Exporting ODB++ directory from Altium to CST Microwave studio

Tags: pcb, rf, altium

I am trying to export a PCB that I created in altium using ODB++ format to CST Microwave studio 2017 , I clicked import and then chose ODB+ and browsed to the zipped file of the ODB++ but it's giving me this error which resulted failure.
[image]

Does anybody have an idea on how to import ODB++ properly?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site. I would ask your CST FAE.

Comment: Thank you for your welcoming !

Comment: I am using a student version so I don't have access to their forums.